# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: server, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am new to servers, so pardon if it's a silly question.
I bought a new Mac and downloaded my ssh key pair file for Amazon AWS EC2 from my dropbox.

I've tried to connect to server as usual:

```
ssh-add ~/.filename.pem 
Identity added: ....
ssh ubuntu@myserverpublicndsaddress.amazonaws.com
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I also tried to get some info:

```
ssh -vv ubuntu@myserverpublicndsaddress.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myserverpublicndsaddress.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Can anyone help with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case assigning elastic IP solved the problem. I have no idea why it is so for Ubuntu, because ssh worked without elastic IP for Amazon Linux.

UPDATE: The reason was simple and stupid. As you know some random IPs in Russia are not available. So, elastic IP had nothing to do with that. Starting VPN allowed to access all my instances.